# Interpetting a stream of cmd_vels

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Investigating weird observed behavior of my TurtleBot3 (previous question: #q300209) I monitored the `cmd_vel` topic during the observed behavior. The conditions are as follows:

- turtlebot3 running kinetic
- map made by gmapping followed by teleoping to visit the maze
- I changed the resolution of the map from 0.05 to 0.01 (I don't think this matters)
- Saved the map
- Stopped gmapping
- start navigation

The robot was able to navigate to a variety of corners of the maze relatively well (it did get confused often.) but when I set up a goal where it would try to drive in reverse (twist x < 0) it would exhibit the bucking behavior. And looking at the cmd_vel message stream I did indeed see negative cmd_vels right next to positive ones. I was not running any teleop at the time. Here is some of the data. I had to search for it but you see negative x's next to positive x's. The maximum linear speed specified for TurtleBot3 is 0.22 so -0.11 is about half the maximum.

Any comments on whether this is normal or weird? And whether this can explain the "bucking" (very intense shuddering motion) that I've reported seeing?

```
linear: 
  x: -0.113387688994
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: -0.661418616772
---
linear: 
  x: -0.12927775085
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: -0.976840138435
---
linear: 
  x: 0.126691520214
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: -1.05274891853
---
linear: 
  x: -0.148515239358
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: -0.77896797657
---
linear: 
  x: -0.127474233508
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: -0.721023142338
---
linear: 
  x: 0.134267643094
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: -1.08932781219
---
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300653/interpetting-a-stream-of-cmd_vels/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-08-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-08-16**:
You should try to find which nodes are publishing on the `/cmd_vel` topic with `rosnode info /cmd_vel` (during run time). Or if you are using a cmd_vel mutliplexer simply echo the topic `/cmd_vel_mux/active` to know what are the inputs for the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is almost certainly to do with your local planner configuration. Have you started with the default parameters and slowly tuned from there?

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2018-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-08-15**:
Interesting! Actually I didn't touch the default that came with the installs. Is there a certain file that I can look at and/or post? The one thing I changed was when I made the map I changed the resolution from 0.05 to 0.01. Could that be it?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2018-08-15**:
I wouldnt think so, but you should try with 0.05 and report back